# Why is my grid not working when my media query activates?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I'm trying to design a simple navbar.
I wanted to place the `<nav>` content (the navigation links) inside the header, aligned with the logo (random image from unsplash.it).
I want this setup to activate above 780px, so I put the code inside a media query, but it does not work.
The browser doesn't even "see" that I gave it the `display: grid` command.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Century Gothic, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}


/* -----DROPDOWN MOBILE MENU----- */

header {
  background: rgba(217, 30, 24, 1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999;
  border: solid white 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header .img {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid black 1px;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

header .img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.025, 1.025);
}

header nav {
  background: rgba(217, 30, 24, .85);
  width: 100vw;
  border: solid white 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav ul {
  width: 20%;
  border: solid white 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(245, 245, 245, .7);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* -----QUERY FOR LARGE SCREENS----- */

@media (min-width:780px) {
  header {
    border: solid white 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
  }
  header .img {
    border: solid blac 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3rem;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  header .img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.025, 1.025);
  }
  header nav {
    background: rgba(217, 30, 24, 1);
    border: solid white 1px;
    width: 50vw;
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    list-style: none;
    border: solid white 0px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  header nav ul li::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    background: ivory;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    transition: ease-in-out .25s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
    -o-transition-duration: .25s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .25s;
  }
  header nav ul li {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    border: solid black 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    -o-transition-duration: .5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
  }
  header nav ul li:hover {
    color: rgba(245, 245, 245, .7);
  }
  header nav ul li:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* -----END LARGE SCREENS QUERY----- */
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#"> <img class="img" src="//unsplash.it/300/100">
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Support us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You've wrapped the image in a link but the image has the grid placement properties, not the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried assigning the grid placement property to the link by writing:

  `header a{
     grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }`
but it does not work. Could you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `<nav>` has

```
position: absolute
```

Once you remove this, your `<nav>` will go into the grid.

To address some other issues that you've mentioned in your comments, please try the following:

Creating a margins-container that you use around your site would be better practise containing your site so it doesn't touch the edges. You can do this by making a class with a restrained width, margin: 0 auto, and a max-width setting. Be aware, however, if placed inside a grid element, it will take up one of the fractions.

I use the following margin-container in my sites:

```
.margins-container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1244px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    @media (max-width: $tablet) {
         margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
     width: 95%;
     }
}
```

However, for now you could just add padding to the header. In the media query, add the following css:

```
header {
  border: solid white 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

This will fix the elements touching the edges. It will also mean you will have less problems with grid's compatibility with browsers such as I.E. To find out more about flex, this is a very in-depth guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I would also remove the border in this media query.

```
header nav {
  background: rgba(217, 30, 24, 1);
  width: 50vw;
}
```

Comment: No worries. There would be a few other things I would consider in your header too, when you get a chance. How do you want your header to look, and why have you set your grid to grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr 1fr?

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thanks a lot! Now I have to understand why it does not fit the viewport, but that's another story I guess lol

Comment: the first and last columns should simply be empty spaces, so the content does not directly stick to the edges of the viewport @IndustryDesigns

Comment: Oh okay, creating a margins-container that you use around your site would be better practise for this. Personally, I would just use display: flex, justify-content: space-between for your header after 780px, as it will cause less issues when you're thinking about browser compatability (grid can be a bit funny).

So, try this code, and let me know how it goes:

@media (min-width:780px) {
header {
  border: solid white 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

Comment: I also notice that the Firefox inspector tool does not "see" the grid element yet... I'm very confused...

Comment: Please see my revised answer to address other issues.

Comment: Surely flexbox is a cleaner alternative, but I wanted to practice with grid because it seems very promising and resourceful. Also, I thought most browsers now are compatible with the Grid level 1 specification... Thanks again

Comment: If you would still like to use grid, it's overkill to add extra grids within it to constrain the width of the inner elements. I'd suggest simply using padding / width + margin autos / using a margins-container, within the header, and then putting the grid within the margins-container.

Comment: Ok, made it work. Now I understand why you would use flexbox on both: the media query overrides the first `display: flex;` statement outside the query and messes up with the logo placement when the screen goes below 780px.

Comment: Maybe I can ask you as a last question if it would be possible to use both grid and flexbox in this case. I understand, it's overkill, but it's for "educational purposes" and curiosity. EDIT: oh, now I see that you added to you first answer, thanks again!

Comment: You can't have both display: grid and display: flex at the same time. You can, however, have elements with your grid that are flex. For instance, in grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1 fr) which creates 3 equal side grids, you might have three divs. These individual divs can have flex. You can also have vice versa, flex elements which contain divs that are grid elements. You can't however, have grid and flex activated on the same element at the same time.

Comment: Often, however, it is useful to use fallbacks like block or flex for if grid doesn't work. if you do have both css stylings declared, if one doesn't work, it will default to the other.

Comment: Ok, got it. I just thought that the media query, as I set it up, would _switch_ between the two; so I have the whole header set to display: flex; for small screens and to display: grid; for larger screens...